# jQuery-UI dialog will not show buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a strange issue, and maybe the solution will be very simple.

My dialog is showing, but without the given buttons. Please help me.

i've got:

```html
 <div id="dialog">Are you sure you want to delete this user?</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openDialog(usrId){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            'Delete': function(){ 
                window.location = '/user/index/remove-user/usrId/'+usrId
            },
            'Cancel': function(){
                $(this).dialog('close')
            }
        }
        }).dialog("open");

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution by myself:

```html
<div id="dialog">Are you sure you want to delete this user?</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialog(usrId){
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "buttons",  
            {
                'Delete':function(){ window.location = '/user/index/remove-user/usrId/'+usrId; $(this).dialog("close"); }
            ,
                'Cancel':function(){ $(this).dialog('close') } 
            }
    ).dialog("open");

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you include all Jquery Dialog js/css files?

Comment: in my <head></head>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">